# How do I avoid the "#DIV/0!" error in Google docs spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, divide-by-zero

I have a column with `average(K23:M23)` that starts out with `#DIV/0!` when the `K23` through `M23` cells are empty. Preferably I'd like to only do the average of cells that contain non-zero, non-blank values. I think it's possible using the query command:

https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=159999

But their example doesn't help me.

Comment: Belongs on webapps.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Odd. 0/3 should be 0, not a divide-by-zero error.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Wrap your formula with `IFERROR`.

```
=IFERROR(yourformula)
```

Comment: This seems to be the simplest answer, although I wish google would add functions to allow checking for specific types of errors.  Wrapping the function in a generic IFERROR makes it harder to debug if a different error is occurring.

Comment: This breaks some very basic principles in logic and programming.  If you know what error/exception you're avoiding, then you should explicitly handle it that way.  Peregrination's answer is better in that sense.  But I'll post yet another answer.

Comment: Might help to know you can specify a default value: `=IFERROR(K23/M23, "Invalid data")`. [Source](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en)

Answer (score 49):

You can use an IF statement to check the referenced cell(s) and return one result for zero or blank, and otherwise return your formula result.

A simple example:

```
=IF(B1=0;"";A1/B1)
```

This would return an empty string if the divisor B1 is blank or zero; otherwise it returns the result of dividing A1 by B1.

In your case of running an average, you could check to see whether or not your data set has a value:

```
=IF(SUM(K23:M23)=0;"";AVERAGE(K23:M23))
```

If there is nothing entered, or only zeros, it returns an empty string; if one or more values are present, you get the average.

Comment: The formula for AVERAGE worked perfectly for me in LibreOffice Calc.

Answer (score 8):

Wrapping the existing formula in IFERROR will not achieve:

> the average of cells that contain non-zero, non-blank values.

I suggest trying:

```
=if(ArrayFormula(isnumber(K23:M23)),AVERAGEIF(K23:M23,"<>0"),"")
```

Comment: Very glad to have come across this, thank you! Wish it were higher up in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are explicitly also asking to handle columns that haven't yet been filled out, and I assume also don't want to mess with them if they have a word instead of a number, you might consider this:

```
=If(IsNumber(K23), If(K23 > 0, ........., 0), 0)
```

This just says... If K23 is a number; And if that number is greater than zero; Then do something .........  Otherwise, return zero.

In ........., you might put your division equation there, such as `A1/K23`, and you can rest assured that K23 is a number which is greater than zero.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the column has text format. Apply number formatting to the cells you're using in the average function.